# jquery: get label value onsubmit

Tags: jquery, input, user-input

```
<form id="test" onsubmit="return checkParams();" method="post" action="">
    <div class="input-inside-label">
        <label for="loc">12345</label>
        <input class="grab-label" value="" type="text" name="loc" id="loc">
    </div>
</form>
```

my input value is empty. However I don't want it to be submitted empty. When the form is submitted I want it to grab the value of the label and then submit it.

However I have quite a few problems doing that. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
$('#test').submit(function(e) {
    if ( $(this).children('.grab-label').val() == '' ) {
        $(this).children('.grab-label').val($(this).closest('label'));
    }
});
```

regards matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, by invoking [`.children()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) you'll only query for *direct* children from the root node. In this case, it can't find `.grab-label` since it's not a direct child.

Use [`.find()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) there. Furthermore, `.closest()` only looksup parent-nodes. In your context it can't find the desired node for that reason. You could use [`.prev()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) starting from the `input` node.

```
$('#test').submit(function(e) {
    var $input = $(this).find('.grab-label');

    if ( !$input.val().length ) {
        $input.val($input.prev().text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`closest` gives you an **ancestor**. But `label`is a **sibling** of the input field. Use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/). `children` will only search in the next level of the DOM, not all descendants. Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead:

```
$(this).find('.grab-label').val($(this).prev('label').text());
```

(you also need [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/))

Or change your HTML to:

```
<div class="input-inside-label">
    <label for="loc">12345
        <input class="grab-label" value="" type="text" name="loc" id="loc">
    </label>
</div>
```

But then it would be easier to use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
$(this).find('.grab-label').val($(this).parent().text());
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to get the **.html()** from that `<label>`

```
$('#test').submit(function(e) {
    if ( $(this).children('.grab-label').val() == '' ) {
        $(this).children('.grab-label').val($(this).closest('label').html());
    }
});
```